# Background Image Not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add background image for the . but It is not working correctly. IN Firefox and Chrome the image came but in Internet Explorer Image not Showing . I have attached my site link and related css code below , can any one pl help to fix this issue. On the home page live chat section.

https://www.autobase.lk/

```
#slideshow_ad{
    width:230px;
    height:240px;
    border:thin solid;
    border-color:#e1e1e1;
    background: white url('../banner/Chat-Banner.png') no-repeat top;
    float:right;
    margin:3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a white background on your condition css for IE8

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link href='http://www.autobase.lk/css/ie8.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://www.autobase.lk/css/directory_ie.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<![endif]-->
```

Your code

```
#slideshow_ad{
    width:230px;
    height:240px;
    border:thin solid;
    border-color:#e1e1e1;
    background: #fff;
    float:right;
    margin:3px;
}
```

Remove background #fff

Answer (score 0):

could you try removing the top?

```
 background: white url('../banner/Chat-Banner.png') no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheets don't appear to be loading.

replace the 2 tags with these, with relative urls:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/directory.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

try editing this line of code

```
background:  url('../banner/Chat-Banner.png') no-repeat top #fff;
```

to

```
background:  url('../banner/Chat-Banner.png') center top no-repeat #fff ;
```